# Постфиксный инкремент, не понимаю как работает

Tags: javascript

Вопрос для вас может банальный но я уже час ни как понять не могу.

```js
let counter = 0;
console.log(counter++ + counter++); // 1
console.log(counter++ + counter++); // 5
```

Откуда взялся 1 во второй строке если постфиксный инкремент возвращает старое число (тот же 0). И потом еще в третьей строке как alert вышел больше реального числа если должно быть наоборот ?!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
let counter = 0;

alert( counter++ + counter++ ); // 1
       ^^ 0 ^^   + ^^ 1 ^^ => 0 + 1 = 1

alert( counter++ + counter++ ); // 5
       ^^ 2 ^^   + ^^ 3 ^^ => 2 + 3 = 5
```

Когда мы встречаем `counter++` в первый раз вместо него в выражение подставляется 0, но в следующем месте, когда он встречается подставляется уже 1, и т.д.

Answer (score 7):

```js
let counter = 0;
console.log( counter++ + counter++ ); // 1
console.log( counter++ + counter++ ); // 5
```

```
let counter = 0;

// вычисление первого операнда:
__temp1 = counter; // 0
counter = counter + 1; // 1
// вычисление второго операнда:
__temp2 = counter; // 1
counter = counter + 1; // 2

console.log( __temp1 + __temp2 ); // 1
```